# "Kyrie eleison": does Spanish have any Greek sayings, like it does Latin? If not, why?

Tags: locuciones, latín, griego

[*Kyrie, eleison*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kyrie) is a Greek expression meaning "Lord, have mercy".

It's been used by Christians since the beginning, and it made its way into the Latin rite of mass, as in the priest (V) is speaking Latin and then he and the congregation (R) just switch to Greek with either *Kyrie, eleison* or *Christe eleison*:

> **V.** Misereátur nostri omnípotens
>   Deus, et, dimíssis peccátis nostris,
>   perdúcat nos ad vitam
>   ætérnam.
>   **R.** *Amen*.
>   **V.** Kýrie, eléison.
>   **R.** *Kýrie, eléison*.
>   **V.** Christe, eléison.
>   **R.** *Christe, eléison*.
>   **V.** Kýrie, eléison.
>   **R.** *Kýrie, eléison*.

This is the way the mass was said everywhere in Spain until [barely 50 years ago](http://www.abc.es/sociedad/20150307/abci-primera-misa-latin-201503051042.html) and, in fact, there are [some places](http://www.unavocesevilla.com/misaenespana.htm) where it is still said like that.

It is also used in [many](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kyrie_en_re_menor,_KV_341_(Mozart)) [classical](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mass_in_B_minor#I._Kyrie_and_Gloria_.28.22Missa.22.29) [music](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=AbueNVkj-r0) [pieces](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=aah_ITLw3R8) meant to be played during mass or just with a religious theme.

**This is also the only case of a Greek expression I've been able to find in Spanish**, and it doesn't even count because it is not used in common conversation.

However, Spanish is ripe with Latin expressions like *vox populi*, *a priori*, *cum laude*, *per se*, *bis*, *mea culpa*, *ecce homo*, etc. Some of them also  have a religious origin.

Given that many Spanish words have Greek roots, I would expect at least a couple Greek expressions too, just like it happens with Latin.

**Are there any Greek expressions in Spanish? And if there are none, why is that?**

Comment: curiosamente la expresión de tu ejemplo existe como una única palabra: [kirieleisón](http://dle.rae.es/srv/search?m=30&w=kirieleis%C3%B3n). De momento no he encontrado expresiones completas, sigo buscando.

Comment: If you accept slightly technical terms how about https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/H%C3%A1pax

Comment: Just wondering: why did you choose V for the priest and R for the congregation?

Comment: **Kirieleison de Muntalbà** es un caballero que aparece en el libro Tirant lo Blanc. En el Quijote hay una referencia al mismo: "-¡Válame Dios! -dijo el cura, dando una gran voz-. ¡Que aquí esté Tirante el Blanco! Dádmele acá, compadre; que hago cuenta que he hallado en él un tesoro de contento y una mina de pasatiempos. Aquí está **don Quirieleisón de Montalbán**, valeroso caballero, y su hermano Tomás de Montalbán, y el caballero Fonseca, con la batalla que el valiente de Tirante hizo con el alano, y las agudezas de la doncella Placerdemivida,..."

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Una locución griega que se oye alguna vez es *[molon labe](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Molon_labe)*. Según la leyenda, cuando el rey persa Jerjes exigió a los espartanos que entregaran sus armas, la respuesta del rey espartano Leónidas fue esa (más o menos, *ven a buscarlas*). Esta frase está inscrita en el pedestal del monumento a Leónidas que hay en el lugar donde antiguamente estaba el desfiladero de las Termópilas.

[image]

Tan escueta respuesta es una muestra del estilo lacónico, palabra derivada, precisamente, del gentilicio de Laconia, la región donde estaba situada Esparta. Los espartanos eran, al parecer, poco amigos de hablar mucho.

Recientemente he leído esta frase escrita por algún independentista catalán, ante la exigencia del gobierno central español de que entregaran las urnas y papeletas que se iban a usar en el referéndum del pasado 1 de octubre. Lo que pasó o dejó de pasar a continuación ya se sale del ámbito de un foro dedicado al lenguaje.

Answer (score 13):

Para este tipo de búsquedas viene bien el [DIRAE](http://dirae.es), ya que te permite buscar según las definiciones de cada entrada del diccionario, incluyendo su clasificación. Por ejemplo, si buscas "loc lat" te aparecen todas las locuciones latinas registradas en el DLE. Sin embargo, si buscas "loc gr" solo se encuentran resultados de palabras que provienen del griego, pero ninguna locución.

La explicación a esto puede ser, en primer lugar, la mayor proximidad del español al latín que al griego clásico, y que los romanos tradujeron las locuciones griegas a su idioma. Te pongo un ejemplo que ilustra ambos puntos:

> ***[deus ex machina](http://dle.rae.es/?id=Daz0cCK)***
>
> Loc. lat.; literalmente 'el dios [que baja] de la máquina'.
>
> 1. m. Teatro. En el teatro de la Antigüedad, personaje que representaba a una divinidad y que, mediante un mecanismo, descendía
>      al escenario para resolver situaciones complicadas o trágicas.
> 2. m. Persona o cosa que, con su intervención, resuelve, de manera poco verosímil, una situación difícil dentro de una obra literaria.
> 3. m. Persona o cosa capaz de solucionar, sin dificultad aparente, todo tipo de situaciones.

Esta locución, aunque latina, alude al teatro de la antigüedad, es decir, al antiguo teatro griego. ¿No debería estar esta locución pues en griego? De hecho, [existía en ese idioma](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Anexo:Locuciones_griegas):

> ***ἀπὸ μηχανῆς Θεός***
>   Apò mēkhanês Theós
>   "Un dios traído con grúa"
>   La frase procede de la manera en que a veces se aparecían las imágenes de dioses en el antiguo teatro griego para resolver una situación sin salida: se les hacía aparecer con una grúa.

Ahora bien, para un español es mucho más sencillo aprenderse y pronunciar "deus ex machina" que "Apò mēkhanês Theós". En el enlace anterior se pueden ver infinidad de locuciones griegas, muchas de las cuales existen en español adaptadas tanto a nuestro idioma como al latín. Por ejemplo:

> ***γνῶθι σεαυτόν***
>   Gnôthi seautón
>   "Conócete a ti mismo"
>
> ***διαίρει καὶ βασίλευε***
>   Diaírei kaì basíleue
>   "Divide y vence"
>
> ***νοῦς ὑγιὴς ἐν σώματι ὑγιεῖ***
>   Noûs hugiḕs en sṓmati hugieî
>   en latín, *Mens sana in corpore sano*
>   "Mente sana en un cuerpo sano"

Como verás por la lista, ninguna de las locuciones expresadas en ella se ha llegado a añadir a nuestro idioma en su versión original en griego, a pesar de que muchas las conocemos.

Comment: ... y adicionalmente seguro también se debe a que las letricas latinas se entienden más fácil que los garabatos griegos. :-)

Answer (score 5):

One example is the useful term *hapax legomenon* meaning a word which only occurs once in a particular corpus. There is an extensive description in the English Wikipedia [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hapax_legomenon) but more importantly it does occur in the Spanish Wikipedia [here](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/H%C3%A1pax) and since at least one of the examples given is different it cannot just be a translation from the English version which implies at least one Spanish speaker thought it worth an entry.

One thing which does surprise me is that *hoi polloi* does not appear in the Spanish Wikipedia in its own right although it is in the entry for *masas* [here](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Masas).

Comment: I don't think I've ever seen *hoi polloi* used in Spanish. I've only seen it in English.

Comment: @Gorpik as you probably guessed I looked for ones I knew from English to see if they were used in Spanish. Curiously there is a Portuguese Wikipedia entry for _hoi polloi_

Comment: Guessed so. But, in my experience, it is not used in Spanish.

Answer (score 4):

*¡Eureka!*

Oh my god, I don't even know how I missed **eureka** when I asked this question:

> [**eureka**](http://dle.rae.es/?id=H68RvEA)
>   Del gr. εὕρηκα *heúrēka* 'he hallado', perf. de εὑρίσκειν *heurískein* 'hallar'.
>
> 1. interj. U. cuando se halla o descubre algo que se busca con afán.

Yes, I know it is an interjection rather than an expression, but it is not that far away from latinisms like *bis*.
Maybe I missed it because it is considered Spanish now (note how the DLE does not use italics for it), but I thought it deserved its own answer anyway.

Comment: No está mal. Lo curioso es que la expresión "eureka" no llegó desde el griego hasta nosotros, como pasó con las expresiones latinas, sino que de repente se puso de moda. En el DLE solo aparece desde 1927 y en las ediciones manuales (en la usual desde 1992). En el CORDE no hay casos antes de 1860, y en la hemeroteca de la BNE el primer caso es de 1845, y menciona una máquina llamada así: "Consiste esta [invención] en una máquina llamada _Eureka_ con la cual se componen versos latinos." ¿Cómo entonces se puso de moda la expresión en España?

Comment: Adelante, por favor, yo ya llevo dos hoy. :-)