# ¿Cómo llegó la expresión "eureka" al español?

Tags: historia

Supongo que todos conocen la palabra **eureka**, [vocablo español que nos llegó del griego](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/a/26226/13628) y que se usa cuando se encuentra algo (normalmente la solución a un problema) tras buscar mucho tiempo.
La mayoría la conocerá por [Arquímedes](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Principio_de_Arqu%C3%ADmedes), pues cuenta la leyenda que, cuando a este sabio griego se le ocurrió la idea que luego derivó en su famoso principio de flotabilidad, salió de su casa gritando *«Eureka! Eureka!»*.

Según esta historia, la expresión podría venir usándose desde el s. III a. C., que es cuando vivió Arquímedes.
Sin embargo, en la respuesta que enlazo al principio, apunta Charlie (acertadamente como siempre) que, lo que es llegar, llegar... del griego no parece que nos llegase, o al menos no de manera natural y directa como otras locuciones latinas; pues apenas hay registrados usos anteriores al s. XIX, ni aparece en los diccionarios hasta mediados del XX, y no parece probable que hasta ese entonces la palabra se viniese usando de manera normal sin que, casualmente, nadie la dejase por escrito.

La verdad es que me ha chocado un poco este descubrimiento.
Buscando por mi cuenta, lo más que he encontrado es [una publicación de 1791](https://books.google.es/books?id=Ac82SP1ca2wC&pg=RA6-PA9-IA7&dq=%22eureka%22&hl=es&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjA8u3qn4XbAhWGcRQKHTlACJs4FBDoAQgmMAA#v=onepage&q=%22eureka%22&f=false) que usa el término de manera bastante natural, sin explicarlo, como si esperase que el lector supiese lo que quiere decir. Además, la publicación está editada en Perú y, aunque posible, me resulta difícil de creer que un vocablo griego pudiera estar usándose en el Perú del s. XVIII (cuando aún era un virreinato español) de manera espontánea o por influencia de nada que no fuese la lengua de la propia España. Pero, lamentablemente, no he hallado ningún otro uso que preceda a ese.

De lo anterior y haciendo buena mi suposición, como mucho podemos concluir que *eureka* ya se usaba en la España de finales del s. XVIII.

Siguen siendo 2000 años de diferencia respecto del uso original. Parece claro entonces que la palabra se introdujo de manera "artificial" en algún momento anterior, pero ¿cuándo y por qué?

**¿Cuál es el primer uso conocido de *eureka* en un texto en español?**

Bonus conspiranoico: ¿realmente dijo Arquímedes *eureka*? ¿Cómo es entonces que no hay registros de tal palabra en un idioma como el español, con tanta influencia de las lenguas clásicas?

Comment: 1) No es lo mismo que el *Principio de Arquímedes*. (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eureka_%28word%29) 2) El relato fue escrito por Vitruvio siglos después (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eureka_%28word%29#cite_ref-4)  (http://penelope.uchicago.edu/Thayer/E/Roman/Texts/Vitruvius/9*.html#Intro.9) 3) Posiblemente (especulación) la palabra "eureka" se difundiera después de la impresión de la obra de Vitruvio en 1486 (https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vitruvio) 4) Muchos piensan que es invención de Vitrivio (https://www.scientificamerican.com/article/fact-or-fiction-archimede/)

Comment: Con el punto 1) intento matizar que el Principio de Arquimedes y el que suba el nivel del agua de una bañera al meterse dentro son dos cosas totalmente diferentes. Me ha parecido que el texto "La mayoría la conocerá por el Principio de Arquímedes, pues cuenta la leyenda que, cuando a este sabio italiano se le ocurrió la idea tras dicho principio, salió de su casa gritando «Eureka! Eureka!»." queda confuso

Comment: Yo creo que descubrí la palabra eureka en "La gallina dijo eureka" de *Les Luthiers*, aunque también va del principio de Arquímedes

Comment: Y como se menciona en
https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/51637/why-do-we-spell-eureka-not-heureka?answertab=votes#tab-top, la busqueda en sus version griega o latina *heureka*, *heureca*, antes de permanecer como eureka ?
https://books.google.nl/books?id=eylNAQAAMAAJ&pg=PP122&lpg=PP122&dq=heureca+latin&source=bl&ots=ECjLRgxkpx&sig=FMdkE6G2cxc_DZvmOJq-k9MPYrI&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjGjdDGwoXbAhVPYVAKHWNGAf0Q6AEIUzAE#v=onepage&q=heureca%20latin&f=false

Comment: Vale que Arquímedes nació en Sicilia, pero por aquel entonces la región pertenecía a la Magna Grecia. Luego era griego, no italiano.

Comment: "Eureca" en un [texto de 1764](https://books.google.es/books?id=d5rumvKxJAYC&dq=%22eureca%22&hl=es&pg=PR6#v=onepage&q=%22eureca%22&f=false): "A cada passo escuchamos à los que, quales otros Archimedes, blasonan hallazgos, quadraturas de circulos, y otros mil inventos, de quienes podemos decir: _Eureca canunt, Corvosque hiantes._"

Answer (score 5, accepted):

He estado haciendo recopilación de datos, dado que este caso parece realmente curioso, y con lo que he recabado creo que puedo plantear una teoría.

Por un lado, los primeros casos de la palabra son relativamente recientes no solamente en español, sino también en los idiomas que nos rodean:

- El primer caso que he encontrado en español es de 1764, como ya expresé en los comentarios.
- Según el [Merriam-Webster](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/eureka), el primer caso en inglés es de 1603.
- Según el [CNRTL](http://www.cnrtl.fr/etymologie/eureka), el primer caso en francés es de 1821.
- Según el [Etymologiebank](http://etymologiebank.nl/trefwoord/eureka), el primer caso en neerlandés es de 1847, y además asegura que el primer caso en inglés es de 1570.

Por otro lado, en la literatura española las referencias al propio Arquímedes aparecen también todas de golpe durante el siglo XVI, encontradas en el CORDE buscando *Archimedes*, *Archímedes* o *Arquímedes*, con una muy leve referencia de un texto de finales del siglo XV (1481, un texto de Antonio de Nebrija que solo cita su nombre).

Así que el siguiente paso fue averiguar el por qué de esto. Resulta que el texto que habla de Arquímedes, sus tratados, principios y la historia del origen de la expresión *Eureka* se escribió dos siglos después del supuesto hecho, que es lo que hace que la historia sea en parte leyenda. Dicho texto es el *De architectura*, escrito por el ingeniero militar y arquitecto romano Marcus Vitruvius Pollio entre los años 30 y 15 antes de Cristo. Recordemos que Arquímedes vivió entre los años 287 y 212 AC.

Según cuenta la [Wikipedia en inglés](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/De_architectura#Survival_and_rediscovery), el hecho de que hoy en día se conozca este texto fue gracias al *scriptorium* de Carlomagno, dado que los manuscritos actuales se basan en la copia allí conservada. A estas copias tuvieron acceso algunos sabios dado que eran de acceso público, pero no recibieron mucha atención hasta el siglo XV. En 1414 la obra de Vitruvio fue "redescubierta" por el humanista florentino Poggio Bracciolini, quien encontró una copia en Suiza en la abadía de San Galo. La obra fue dada a conocer y a finales de siglo, en 1486, se publicó una primera edición impresa, a la que siguió una que incluía ilustraciones en 1511.

A partir de esta obra fue ya cuestión de tiempo que los estudiantes con acceso a la obra descubrieran la historia de la corona de Arquímedes y comenzaran a usar la interjección *Eureka*. La primera edición en español se publicó en 1582, gracias a Miguel de Urrea y Juan Gracián.