# ¿Existe el uso de «hoi polloi» en el idioma española?

Tags: vocabulario

El termino griego «hoi polloi» es usado en el idioma inglés. ¿Se usa en el idioma español tambien?

¿Si yo lo usara, entendería un hispanohablante?

Si no, ¿cuál sería el termino mas adecuado para reemplazarlo?

Comment: Relacionada : https://spanish.stackexchange.com/questions/22791/kyrie-eleison-does-spanish-have-any-greek-sayings-like-it-does-latin-if-not/22857#22857

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**No, no existe en Castellano y por lo tanto un hispanohablante no tendría la menor idea de a qué alude la expresión  "*hoi polloi*"**

En cuanto a términos de reemplazo, — de acuerdo a la connotación que se intente darle— podría usarse:

- tono **neutro**

  > ***Hombre común***
- **despectivo**

  > - ***plebeyo*** [fuente](https://dle.rae.es/plebeyo?m=form) relativo a la plebe (al pueblo) o la clase baja, como opuesto a al nobleza o clase alta
  > - alguien del ***populacho***
  > - o de perteneciente a la ***chusma*** [ver](https://dle.rae.es/chusma?m=form), o ***gentuza*** [ver](https://dle.rae.es/gentuza?m=form)

Answer (score 2):

The obvious replacement is the Latin equivalent which was *plebs* since the Greek expression does not seem to be widely used in Spanish if at all. According to the [Dictionary of the language](https://dle.rae.es/plebe?m=form)

> plebe
>   Del lat. plebs, plebis.
>
> 1. f. Clase social más baja.
> 2. f. En la antigua Roma, clase social que carecía de los privilegios de los patricios.
> 3. f. En el pasado, clase social común, fuera de los nobles, eclesiásticos y militares.